# Many to many relation without association table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, many-to-many

From my knowledge, if you make many to many relations I always used to use `association table`. Nevertheless, now I have requirement from business (not sure if they have db knowledge) to create `relationships` between two tables directly. To me that's not possible. They saying that I have to do as follows, so for example what they saying is:

```
TableA
ID (PK)
refKey

TableB
ID (PK)
refKey
```

Make many to many between `TableA.refKey` and `TableB.refKey.` Is something like that possible?? I've tried but postgres yield to create `unique`. And.. if I create `unique` for any of `refKey` from my knowledge it will be `1:M or M:1`. Am I missing something? Nevertheless if you say that's possible please of sample code to initiate such connection based on that particular example.

Comment: A many-to-many relationship is always implemented through a mapping table.

Comment: and there is really no way to connect (without association table) them both? Just need to be 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right there will only be many-to-one or one-to-many relationships. What you need is a joining table, for example:

```
create table A_B (
    A_id bigint references A,
    B_id bigint references B
)
```

Then you can have as many rows with the same `A_id` or `B_id` as you want. That results in a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* create a many-to-many relationship with just two tables.  This is not a best practice, but it might be practical in some circumstances.

In Postgres, the simplest way is to have an array of ids that references the second table:

```
create table a (
   a_id int generated always as identity,
   b_ids[] int
);
```

Why is this generally a bad idea?

- You cannot validate the foreign key constraints easily.  (Well, you can using a trigger or UDF.)
- You cannot easily guarantee uniqueness.  (Well, you can using a fancy `check` constraint.)
- You cannot easily see the "inverse" relationship.  (Well, you can using `unnest()`.)
- You cannot easily index the array elements in `a`.

In other words, lots of the "built-in" functionality is missing when you do this.

I should note that you can also do this with JSON as well as arrays.

Comment: You are correct, wrong 'button', and thanks for pointing it out.